# Unable to hook into custom filter hook using add_filter()

Tags: wordpress

I am very new to Wordpress Development so this question might be silly .May be I do not understand the concept of custom filters in Wordpress . So far I have used Wordpress's own filter hooks to change values like below :

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ffl_add_footer') ; // add footer to the blog content
```

I have just started learning about custom filters that you can code . So my understanding is you use apply_filters() to set up a filter hook to a value($var below) like below :

```
apply_filters('filter_tag' , $var ) ;
```

Later you hook into that filter and use a callback function to modify the value ($var) like below :

```
add_filter('filter_tag , 'callback');
```

Your callback would be like below :

```
function callback($var) {
//modify $var 
return $var
}
```

So I was testing this understanding with a code like below :

```
function callback($var){
    return ($var.'append');
}


$var = 'testing';
echo $var;
$var1 = apply_filters('custom_filter', $var);
add_filter('custom_filter' , 'callback');
echo $var1;
```

This echoes **testingtesting** while I was expecting **testingtestingappend** . The callback function doesnt seem to get called at all as I tried exit() inside the callback . Am I understanding this wrong or is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: In your last code example you are applying the filter before you have actually registered it. Try changing the sequence of `apply_filter` and `add_filter` in order to get the expected result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `add_filter` **after** `apply_filters` has been executed. You need to call it earlier so your callback gets registered first, then `apply_filters` will execute it

For example (untested, but it should work):

```
function callback($var){
    return ($var.'append');
}
add_filter('custom_filter' , 'callback'); // register the callback

$var = 'testing';
echo $var; // testing

$var1 = apply_filters('custom_filter', $var); // apply registered callbacks
echo $var1; // testingappend
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I thought it worked the other way . However , now I have a related question . What happens when you try to hook into a filter of an existing plugin (say plugin named B) . How do I ensure my plugins's add_filter() is executed first and later Bs apply_filter() is executed . The plugins seems to run in an alphabetical order . Does that mean my plugin needs to be named A ?

Comment: The [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) functions accepts up to 4 parameters, being the third one the *priority*. This is what WordPress uses to determine the order of execution of every registered callback. The lower the value the earlier the callback gets executed (check the documentation for more details.) Oh, also please consider marking this answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped @Knownow.